# are there tax consequences for transferring a family member's high interest debt to my 0% interest balance transfer card

Tags: credit-card

I am considering Citibank balance transfer credit card for myself (with a 0% balance transfer offer)and wish to help a family member who has high interest debt and want to transfer their balance to mine so they can get out of debt faster. Is this possible and/or commonly done? Also is there any tax consequence for doing this?

Comment: Can you edit and add country tag

Comment: Tax aside, are you prepared to assume legal responsibility for their debt?

Comment: You have effectively _gifted_ your family member with the amount of the high-interest debt since you are now solely responsible for paying it off, and the family member is totally off the hook.  So, if the debt is more than $15K, a gift tax return might be needed.

Answer (score 2):

If you give them a loan (do document that) and don't charge interest you effectively give them a gift of whatever interest would be fair (check the federal rate and add a percent or two).
So the answer is no unless that amount of interest exceeds $15k in which case you have a whole host of other issues to worry about.

Comment: This assumes US, which is likely given Citibank but not explicit.

Comment: Yes, the question can't be answered without assuming location (and US seems far more likely than anything else).